# Difference between "jupyter notebook" and "python -m notebook" commands

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

For opening jupyter notebook from cmd in windows we can use the following commands:

1. `jupyter notebook`
2. `python -m notebook`

What are the difference between these two commands?

Comment: The first starts a `jupyter` kernel and `notebook` tab in your browser.  The second doesn't work unless you have a Python script called `notebook.py`.  Where did you read that you can use *2*?

Comment: @hpaulj You can try opening jupyter notebook with the second command as well. It works. Just want to know the difference